# Struts2 Action Not Calling from URL

Tags: java, struts2

```
String url = ipaddressPortnumber + request.getContextPath() + "/registerconfig.action?lvd=" + lvd;
```

`lvd` is a class;
when i want to hit on the action `(registerconfig.action?lvd="+lvd)` given on `url`
got a error like below, how can I solve it
[image: Error page after hitting the action button]

Comment: what kind of class is `lvd`? and pls post the error stack

Comment: lvd is a simple class which contained getter setter data and constructor

Comment: please post as code/text not prints!

Answer (score 1):

The result `input`  is required to add to the action config because before executing the action it has validation errors. The flow will return back to the `index.jsp` where you can fix errors before submitting the form. The action won't execute if it has errors. Add this code to the action config

```
<result name="input">index.jsp</result>
```